# Using part of a keyword to extract a full keyword in SAS

Tags: compiler-errors, sas, macros, sas-macro

In my project i am taking a users input and one of the variables is key to extract. This variable is year but may be written for some datasets as say "Graduation_year" where in others it may be say "Year_of_purchase" and so on. What i need to do is take this variable out of a list to be used separately from the remainder of the list. From the example below what my desired outcome looks like is as follows:
Input -> (Gender Graduation_Year Course_Name)
Outputs -> Var_of_importance = Graduation_year and Remainder_vars= Gender Course_name.

The code i am using so far has come across an error as i'm trying to update a macro variable at each iteration of the second loop called size.

The code is as follows:

```
%macro Year_finder(var_list);

%local size;
%Put The variables are: &var_list.;
%let Keyword_loc=%Index(&var_list.,Year);

%put The location of the keyword Year begins at place number &Keyword_loc.;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&var_list.));
    %let word_&i.=%length(%sysfunc(scan(&var_list.,&i.)));
    %put The length of %sysfunc(scan(&var_list.,&i.)) is &&word_&i.;
%end;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&var_list.));
    
    %if i=1 %then %do;
        %if &&word_&i. LT &Keyword_loc. and &&word_(&i.+1)+1 GT &Keyword_loc. %then Word = %sysfunc(scan(&var_list.,&i.));
        %let size=&&word_&i.;

        %put The step number is step &i.;
        %put The &i.th word has a length of &&word_&i.;
        %put Initial length is &size.;
    %end;
    
    %else %do;
        %eval(&size. = &size.+ &&word_&i. + 1);
        %if &size. LT &Keyword_loc. and &size. + &&word_(&i.+1) + 1 GT &Keyword_loc. %then Word = %sysfunc(scan(&var_list.,(&i.+1)))

        %put This step number is step &i.;
        %put The length variable = &size.;
        %put The word is &Word.;
    %end;
%end;

%mend;

%Year_finder(Gender Graduation_Year Course_Name);
```

At the moment this seems like it will do what i want it to but as i cant get past this error i cannot verify it works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, the easiest is to check if each word individually contain "year" and  add them to the desired output macro variable. The following should work:

```
%macro Year_finder(var_list);

   * Initialize output variables;
   %global Var_of_importance Remainder_vars;
   %let Var_of_importance = ;
   %let Remainder_vars = ; 

   * Go through words from var_list;
   %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&var_list.));
      * Add word to var_of_importance if it contain "year" (not case sensitive);
      %if %index(%lowcase(%scan(&var_list.,&i.)),year) %then %do;
         %let Var_of_importance = &Var_of_importance %scan(&var_list.,&i.);
      %end;
      %else %do;
         * Add word to Remainder_vars if it does not contain "year";
         %let Remainder_vars = &Remainder_vars %scan(&var_list.,&i.);
      %end;
   %end;

%mend;

%Year_finder(Gender Graduation_Year Course_Name);
```

Your original code has several problems

- You never mention the variables Var_of_importance or Remainder_vars that are your end goal. Note that these should be global variables.
- You miss an ampersand in your first if statement. Change `%if i=1 %then %do;` to `%if &i=1 %then %do;`
- In your next if statements miss a `%sysevalf()` to evaluate the complicated expression and you miss a `%let` in your `%then word =`
- If you want to refer to the next index you cannot write `&&word_(&i.+1)`. Instead you can write `%superq(word_%eval(&i+1))`. For details see [Resolving macro containing %eval in macro variable name, SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064369/resolving-macro-containing-eval-in-macro-variable-name-sas)
- You keep comparing the lengths of each word (`&&word_&i.`) to the location of "year" (`&Keyword_loc.`). However, you should compare the accumulated length, which you call `size`
- You have a eval function without any other statements, as noted by Tom in another answer. You probably wanted to write `%let size = %eval(&size.+ &&word_&i. + 1);`

Comment: Thank you Jeppe for your help. I am still getting used to some of the more difficult macro functions and so have missed out on their functions. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
%eval(&size. = &size.+ &&word_&i. + 1);
```

is generating an invalid SAS statement. Depending on the result of the comparison of the left and right side of the equal sign it will generate one of these two statements.

```
0;
1;
```

I suspect you either wanted a %LET statement of some sort.

```
%let size = %eval(&size.+ &&word_&i. + 1);
```

Or if you did intend to use the macro to generate a 0 or 1 that can be used in the middle of another statement then do not include the semi-colon after the %eval().